# How to iterate over an "Input" function?

Tags: functions, programming, string-manipulation, iterators

I wasn't sure what to name this title, I will explain this code just incase some people actually aren't running it on Mathematica..This code will ask you "what is #1 * #2", where #1 and #2 are random integers between 1 and 12 as defined by a and b.. If you get the answer right it says "Great Job" but if you get it wrong it will say "Try again"..

I guess I have 2 questions:

How can I have this repeat multiple times (well use 3 iterations), so the input window would pop ups and ask 3 different multiplication problems...

Assuming we get it wrong, how can I have the same input window ask the same question again until it is answered right?

```
 Clear[answer,a,b,list];

 a = RandomInteger[{1, 12}];
 b = RandomInteger[{1, 12}];
 list = Input["what is " <> ToString[a] <> " times " <> ToString[b] <> "."];
 If[list == a*b, Print["Great Job"], Print["Try Again"]]
 list
```

Let me know if I need to clarify anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Do[SeedRandom[];
 a = RandomInteger[{1, 12}];
 b = RandomInteger[{1, 12}];
 list = Input[
   "what is " <> ToString[a] <> " times " <> ToString[b] <> "?"];
 If[list == a*b, Print["Great Job"], 
  While[list != a b, 
   list = Input[
     "Try again; what is " <> ToString[a] <> " times " <> 
      ToString[b] <> "?"]
   ]
  ]
 , 3]
```